# Request object does not return correct host name

Tags: request

we have hosting for multiple domains and a background redirect algorithm. redirect function is in python and checks:

request.host

in stead of returning abc.com or xyz.com now host started to return about a couple of hours ago

us-central1-functionname.cloudfunctions.net

for all hosted domians and redirects stopped.

we cannot get the correct host name any more.

Comment: This is a firebase project, using Google Cloud Functions written in Python 3.7. Has multiple custom domains.

Comment: This is off-topic here. You can ask questions about programming in Python on [so].

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using :

`request.host`
or
`request.host_url`,

use:

`request.headers.get("X-Forwarded-Host")` to get abc.com or xyz.com.